# HTTP Post That Requires Associative Array In Java

Tags: java, arrays, api, http, associative-array

I am trying to make an API call in java to an HTTP Post that requires an associative array, in my case the array is '$range' see below.

I was able to successfully make the call using PHP with the follow code:

```
//THIS WORKS - IN PHP

$url = 'http://demo.com/ajax/otherVariables/getMetrics';

$range = array(
    'from' => '06/22/2018 00:00',
    'to' => '07/21/2018 23:59',
    'timezone' => 'US/Eastern'
);

$postData = array(
    '_e662555' => $hash,
    'range' => $range,
    'camps' => 10001,
    'key' => 'custom.w'
);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postData));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

I've been trying to do it with a HashMap and Unirest in java and haven't had any luck.

```
//THIS DOESNT WORK - IN JAVA

Map<String, String> range = new HashMap<String, String>();
range.put("from", "06/22/2018 00:00");
range.put("to", "07/21/2018 23:59");
range.put("timezone", "US/Eastern");

Map<String, Object> fields = new HashMap<String, Object>();
fields.put("_e662555", token);
fields.put("range", range);
fields.put("camps", 10001);
fields.put("key", "custom.w");

HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.post("http://demo.com/ajax/otherVariables/getMetrics")
        .fields(fields)
        .asJson();

System.out.println(response.getBody());
```

I think the issue is with the associative array. It doesn't seem to wanna handle the HashMap the same way PHP handles their associative arrays.

I've tried using an array of arrays:

```
String[] from = {"from","06/22/2018 00:00"};
String[] to = {"to","07/21/2018 23:59"};
String[] timezone = {"timezone","US/Eastern"};
String[][] range = {from,to,timezone};
```

Also tried a list with key,value objects

```
List<Range> range = new ArrayList<Range>();
range.add(new Range("from","06/22/2018 00:00"));
range.add(new Range("to","07/21/2018 23:59"));
range.add(new Range("timezone","US/Eastern"));

class Range{
public String key,value;

public Range(String key, String value){
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
}
```

Not having any luck tho.

As mentioned above I think the issue is with the associative array. We just need it to behave the same way it does in PHP but in JAVA.

Does anyone know how we can accomplish this? I am open to using any libraries or any other solutions.

Comment: *We just need it to behave the same way it does in PHP*: well, how does it behave in PHP? What does the PHP code do? What is the body of the post request. If you knew that, it would be much easier to do the same thing in Java.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out after doing a bunch of testing using postman.

This is the syntax you need for anyone that is working with a more complex array

```
HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.post("http://demo.com/ajax/otherVariables/getMetrics")
                  .field("_e662555",token)
                  .field("range[from]","06/22/2018 00:00")
                  .field("range[to]","07/21/2018 23:59")
                  .field("range[timezone]","US/Eastern")
                  .field("camps",10001)
                  .field("key","custom.w")
                  .asJson();
```